# Increment and Decrement button via Material UI ButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, buttongroup

I want to create a increment / decrement button with material ui ButtonGroup. the button is like this image at first.

[image: The first part of ButtonGroup]

When user clicked on the button, the second part of ButtonGroup will show (Like Image Below).

[image: Second part of the ButtonGroup]

how can I achieve this? Please Help.

thanks in advance.

## **Code**

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import ButtonGroup from "@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup";

class GroupedButtons extends React.Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter + 1 }));
  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter - 1 }));
  };
  render() {
    const Btn = (
     <>
      <Button disabled>{this.state.counter}</Button>
      <Button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</Button>
     </>
    );

    return (
      <ButtonGroup size="small" aria-label="small outlined button group">
        <Button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</Button>
        {this.state.counter > 0 && Btn}
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default GroupedButtons;
```

something like code above. but it doesn't work.

Comment: hello, please, add sample code

Comment: Hello, updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Material UI `ButtonGroup` expects only `Button` children. You pass `React.Fragment` as a child.

You can change the code this way:

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import ButtonGroup from "@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup";

class GroupedButtons extends React.Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter + 1 }));
  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ counter: state.counter - 1 }));
  };
  render() {
    const displayCounter = this.state.counter > 0;

    return (
      <ButtonGroup size="small" aria-label="small outlined button group">
        <Button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</Button>
        {displayCounter && <Button disabled>{this.state.counter}</Button>}
        {displayCounter && <Button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</Button>}
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default GroupedButtons;
```

See live demo here:

[image: Edit thirsty-rain-i1tzi]

Comment: Yes. thank you. but when I click plus button, i want this button (plus button) not to move. this is what I see in your live demo. how can I animate minus and number part when It appears? @anton-novik

Comment: It's app styles, not your component. I've removed the app alignment not to confuse you (https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-rain-i1tzi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: thank you very much. I've almost got it @anton-novik

Comment: If it answers your question, you can accept it (for more info see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

with hooks :
I am using (`product ['countInStock']`) as an example of stock quantity

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
return (
   <ButtonGroup size="small" aria-label="small outlined button group">
   <Button
     disabled={counter >= product["countInStock"]}
     onClick={() => {
       setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
     }}
   >
     +
   </Button>
   <Button disabled>{counter}</Button>}
   <Button
     disabled={counter <= 0}
     onClick={() => {
       setCounter((counter) => counter - 1);
     }}
   >
     -
   </Button>
 </ButtonGroup>
)
```